# Example of simple parsers in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I have the following parsers functions

```
import Data.Char
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]

return' :: a -> Parser a
return' v = \inp -> [(v,inp)]

failure :: Parser a
failure = \inp -> []

item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
         [] -> []
     (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse p inp = p inp

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse p inp = p inp

(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = \inp -> case parse p inp of
            [] -> parse q inp
     [(v,out)] -> [(v,out)]
```

So far so good, they can be loaded into ghci. But when I add the following function

```
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do x <- item
           if p x then return x else failure
```

I obtain an error. Could you tell what's going on?

Comment: The function is called `return'` not `return`.

Comment: My bad, but I'm still obtain an error, it goes like this: `No instance for (Monad ((->) String) arising from a do statement`

Answer (score 1):

The type of `x` in the `do` block of `sat` is `[(Char, String)]`. This is because `item` has the type `String -> [(Char, String)]` or `(->) String [(Char, String)]` and you are using the `Monad` instance for `(->) String`, so what is "contained" in a `(->) String [(Char, String)]` is a `[(Char, String)]`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do (x :: [(Char, String)]) <- item
           if p x then return' x else failure
```

`p` is a function from a `Char` to `Bool`; it doesn't accept a list of possible parsing results. The only sensible thing to do with `p` is `filter` the results based on whether the `Char` matches `p`. This still results in `[]` when the result doesn't match `p`.

```
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do (x :: [(Char, String)]) <- item
           return $ filter (p . fst) x
```

If we drop `ScopedTypeVariables`, we need to drop the type signature I added for illustration.

```
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do x <- item
           return $ filter (p . fst) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `do` blocks requires that your `Parser` is an instance of the `Monad` class. Since your `Parser` type is an alias for a function type `String -> [(a, String)]` and functions are not instances of `Monad`, this is why you get the error. You could write your function without using `do` notation:

```
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p [] = []
sat p (c:cs) = if p c then [(c, cs)] else []
```

Comment: Functions are instances of `Monad`, or have been since [base 4.6.0.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0). Before that the `Monad` instance for functions was given by `instance Monad ((->) r) where return = const; f >>= k = \r -> k (f r) r` in [`Control.Monad.Instances`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html).